# llvm : detect if/else conditions in function pass

Tags: llvm, static-analysis

I'm trying to write an LLVM analysis pass (function pass) which detects loop and if/else conditions to indentify possibles function call sequences and impossibles ones.

To detect loops i used LoopInfo from LoopInfoWrapperPass, someone know if there is a such tool for if/else conditions ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now i'm thinking about it, i wonder if i couldn't just use BasicBlocks name to do this. Since if basic block are named "if.then / if.else"

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to detect simple if-else structures(whithout any other nested if-else) then it is straight forward, 2 blocks which has just one and same succesor(BB->getUniqueSuccessor ()) and alse one and same predesessor(BB->getUniquePredecessor()) are "if" and "else" blocks. for nested structures it would be a bit complicated, a recurssive function which also needs dominator frontiers information

Answer (score -1):

You can use block-name.
If your BasicBlock is `B`, use `B->getName()` to get the name of block.

```
if.then  => if block
if.else  => else-if block
if.end   => block after if-else blocks
for.cond => condition of for loop
for.body => body of foor loop
for.end  => block after foor loop
```